# Splitting end of text at period creates empty string

Tags: javascript, regex, console

Given the following text

```
var text="unicorns! and rainbows? and, cupcakes.Hello this is splitting by sentences. However, I am not sure.";
```

I want to split at every period, there is a period at the end of the sentence and it splits it into an empty string as shown.

```
(4) ["unicorns! and rainbows? and, cupcakes", "Hello this is splitting by sentences", " However, I am not sure", ""]
```

What is a good way to split at the period using . but accounting for the end of the text?

Comment: use `.filter(Boolean)` at the end, that will strip out any empty strings

Comment: Why don't you just check if the last string is empty, and remove it if so?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `.filter(Boolean)` to strip out any empty strings, like so:

```js
var text="unicorns! and rainbows? and, cupcakes.Hello this is splitting by sentences. However, I am not sure.";
var splitText = text.split(".");
var nonEmpty = splitText.filter(Boolean);
// var condensed = text.split(".").filter(Boolean);
console.log(nonEmpty);
```

It may seem like a strange way to do it, but it's easy/efficient, and the concept works like this:

```
var arr = ["foo", "bar", "", "baz", ""];
var nonEmpty = arr.filter(function (str) {
  return Boolean(str);
});
```

This uses the power of coercion to determine whether the string is empty or not. The only value of a string that will coerce to `false` is, in fact, an empty string `""`. All other string values will coerce to `true`. That is why we can use the Boolean constructor to check whether a string is empty or not.

Additionally, if you want to trim the leading/trailing whitespace off of each sentence, you can use the `.trim()` method, like so:

```js
var text="unicorns! and rainbows? and, cupcakes.Hello this is splitting by sentences. However, I am not sure.";
var nonEmpty = text.split(".").filter(Boolean).map(str => str.trim());
console.log(nonEmpty);
```

Answer (score 0):

That's how `String#split` works (and it's kind of logical that it is). There is nothing after the `.` in the string so it should be an empty string. If you want to get rid of the empty strings in the array you can filter them out using `Array#filter` (using an arrow function to mke it simple):

```
var result = text.split(".").filter(s => s);       // an empty string is falsy so it will be excluded
```

Or use `String#match` with a simple regex in one go like:

```
var result = text.match(/[^.]+/g);                 // matches any sequence of character that are not a '.'
```

**Example:**

```js
var text="unicorns! and rainbows? and, cupcakes.Hello this is splitting by sentences. However, I am not sure.";

var resultFilter = text.split(".").filter(x => x);
var resultMatch = text.match(/[^.]+/g);

console.log("With filter:", resultFilter);
console.log("With match:", resultMatch);
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding `filter(Boolean)` to `split` is certainly a workaround, but the problem can be handled directly (and flexibly) by giving a regex to `split`.

For example, you can split on a regex that ignores periods completely or one that preserves all periods (or other punctuation marks):

```js
const text = "unicorns! and rainbows? and, cupcakes.Hello this is splitting by sentences. However, I am not sure.";

// discard periods
console.log(text.match(/[^.]+/g));

// discard periods and leading whitespace
console.log([...text.matchAll(/(.+?)(?:\.\s*)/g)].map(e => e[1]));

// keep periods
console.log(text.match(/(.+?)\./g));

// keep periods periods but trim whitespace
console.log([...text.matchAll(/(.+?\.)\s*/g)].map(e => e[1]));

// discard various sentence-related punctuation
console.log(text.match(/[^.?!]+/g));
```